# Help me understand these topological properties of linear groups.

Tags: group-theory, algebraic-topology, linear-groups

I'm studying Linear groups and already bamboozled after proving that there is a bijective correspondence from $SU_2$to $S^3$ and $SU_2$ can be thought of as the set of unit vectors in the quaternion algebra! [what could be more interesting than visualizing groups? :-)]

I have luckily encountered two awesome questions-

$1.$ There is no way to make **2-sphere** into a group.

$2.$ The only spheres on which one can define **CONTINUOUS GROUP LAWS** are the **1-sphere** and **3-sphere**!

I don't know how to prove these results, I know basic algebraic topology, need help to know if these results have simple proofs and please share some articles describing more about the geometry of linear groups.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe that there are proofs in hatcher's algebraic topology and also vector bundles/k-theory. Look for "Real division algebras."

Comment: can you give me some intuition? @AndresMejia

Comment: Well, you can rule out the even dimensional spheres by noting that a topological group acts on itself freely, and a group action determines "translations" by a nontrivial group element $g \in S^{2n}$, but then the map $x \mapsto gx$ must have a fixed point since it is  a map $S^{2n} \to S^{2n}$, which is basically the content of the hairy ball theorem.

Comment: @MathCosmo The proof of 2. is highly non-trivial. One proof that I know involves cohomology graded ring as a Hopf algebra. Where did you get that from? It is unlikely that anyone gave it as an exercise.

Comment: There is a weaker theorem that is easier to prove: it's 2. with "continuous" replaced with "differentiable" (i.e. the only spheres that can be Lie groups are $S^0,S^1,S^3$). You "simply" show that the de Rham cohomology of a Lie group of degree 1 and degree 3 are linked; and this isn't the case for any other sphere